# I am getting Connection Errror while running doing locust load testing using gunicorn for fastapi

Tags: python, gunicorn, fastapi, locust

I am trying to do loadtesting using locust for fastapi application using gunicorn

below is my loadtesting code

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, between

file_path = "file_path"

class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(3, 10)

    @task
    def test_compress(self):
        data = {
            'compress_quality' : 30,
            'compress_threshold' : 20
        }
        files = {
            'input_file': ( 'file.jpg', open(file_path, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg'),
            
         }
        result = self.client.post("/compress", files=files, data=data)
```

i am running my fastapi application with following command

```
gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker —-threads 16 chdir app main:app -b 0.0.0.0:7113
```

when i start load testing after 1 or 2 requests, the requests starts getting Connection Error , while some of them run

I want to remove this Connection Error

```
ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')))

ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

Comment: ”Connection reset by peer” means gunicorn closed the connection. Look in to gunicorns configuration, thats most likely the root cause.

Comment: @Cyberwiz, can you please be more specific, I am new to using guicorn

Comment: Sorry, while I’m pretty good at locust and have used gunicorn a little bit, i dont know what this might be about..